# Page moving left when focusing on textbox in Phonegap Ios app

Tags: jquery, css, cordova, ios7

When i focusing on the textbox in my app my page is moving left,

The css file is of my page:

```
#page{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
}
```

Thanks in advance...